# How can I change MFC Command Button arrow or Remove the arrow From Button

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I'm beginner to mfc Visual C++, my question is that i want to remove or change Command Button arrow from button, Or stop showing arrow with command button. tell Me if it is possible or not. & If possible then what should i do, which function to use.

Comment: Any reason for not using CButton ?

Comment: I want stylish button, If you know more about CButton then please can you tell me how to change CButton's hover effect, like Windows 10 Calculator or whatever color, default color is light blue, i want to change it.

Comment: `CMFCButton` and `CMFCButton::SetTextHotColor`came to the rescue!